# Replace a letter in a string with either of two possible letters.

Tags: python, string, list, replace, permutation

```
a = ["cat","bat","fat"]
where "t" can be replaced by either "b" or "r"
```

So, the output should be a list of all possible cases of such a replacement.

```
cases = ["cab","car","bab","bar","fab","far"]
```

Comment: `cases = a + [A.replace("t", "b") for A in a] + [A.replace("t", "r") for A in a]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
res = []
for word in a:
    res.append(word.replace("t","r"))
    res.append(word.replace("t","b"))
print res
```